# Really Low sound Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have my volume all the way up on my laptop and when I go to listen to music or watch shows on my laptop the volume is way below what it should be. I don't know what to do. I went into the sound controls and tried messing with it but its not working..Any ideas?

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop? (eg: HP Pavilion dv6)

Comment: @ G Koe HP Pavilion g4

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the speaker icon in the lower left corner on the desktop (near the clock) and raising the volume all the way, and then ALSO turn up the volume using the <kbd>f10/(speaker)+</kbd> key.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ G Koe I did try that and still didnt work I dont get whats wrong with it